# How to view bash commands when executed from a node script

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a node app where I'm using a webhook from bitbucket to trigger a bash script to run some commands to deploy my app. It works, however I can't view any of the commands being run (ie progress commands echo'd). How can I achieve this?

Here is the relevant code:

```
  var shellPath = path.join(__dirname + '../../deploy/deploy.sh');
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;

  function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stout: ', stdout)
    console.log('error: ', error)
    console.log('stderr: ', stderr)
  }

  exec(shellPath, puts);
```

deploy.sh -

```
echo Preparing to Git Fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
echo Preparing to clean
git clean -f
echo Preparing to pull
git pull
echo preparing to pull
npm i --production
echo preparing to restart pm2
pm2 restart client-www
echo Finished deploy
```

Comment: See: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just output the result to a file like:

```
var shellPath = path.join(__dirname + '../../deploy/deploy.sh > ./output.log');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stout: ', stdout)
  console.log('error: ', error)
  console.log('stderr: ', stderr)
}

exec(shellPath, puts);
```

and use this to watch file and print output  [always-tail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/always-tail)

```
var Tail = require('always-tail');
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = "./output.log";

if (!fs.existsSync(filename)) fs.writeFileSync(filename, "");

var tail = new Tail(filename, '\n');

tail.on('line', function(data) {
  console.log("got line:", data);
});


tail.on('error', function(data) {
  console.log("error:", data);
});

tail.watch();
```